# Solvable, non-nilpotent group with nilpotent commutator subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

What is the smallest example of a finite solvable, non-nilpotent group $G$, such that its derived subgroup $G'$ is nilpotent, but not abelian?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some context indicating why you are looking for such a group.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$ has order $24$ and derived subgroup isomorphic to the quaternion group of order $8$.  You can check that no smaller group meets your requirements.